# Cannot run program "sh": Launching failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, sh

I downloaded cygwin and install. Then copy the ndk file to android folder. The path is `C:\Program Files\Android\android-ndk-r9b then add this path to systemVaraible`. Then choosen ndk location in Eclipse preference. Then right click the project, select `AndroidToold->Add Native support`
I'm getting this error:  `Build of configuration Default for project ImageTargets`

(Cannot run program "sh": Launching failed)

Then open the cygwin terminal type `$ cd /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Android/androi-ndk-r9b/samples/san-angles ndk-build`

Below error i'm getting. Where i made mistake?

```
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need cygwin to work with NDK r9b on Windows. But whether you have cygwin installed or not, you should avoid spaces in the file names for your Android NDK or SDK installations. The easy fix would be to specify the path using short name, e.g. `C:\Progra~1\Android\android-ndk-r9b`.

See more at [The Android emulator is not starting, showing "invalid command-line parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/the-android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter), or [Using Proguard for Android in Eclipse got Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421262/using-proguard-for-android-in-eclipse-got-error).

Comment: I changed my path name like C:\Development\android-ndk-r9b but still showing the same error. And set this path to system variable also. But it's not working

Comment: I believe the error message also changed; would you like to disclose?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error on Windows and it was resolved by setting the correct path for Android NDK in the Eclipse workpace (**Preferences->Android->NDK**).

Answer (score 0):

the "Cannot run program "sh": Launching failed" may come from a bad eclipse configuration.
You can try to reset C/C++ Build configuration, inside your project settings:

[image: C/C++ build settings in eclipse]

Also on Windows, like Alex Cohn said, you don't need cygwin and can directly launch "ndk-build.cmd" script that is inside your NDK installation folder.